Durrett Probability 5th edition: Ex5.3.1
Suppose $y$ is recurrent and for $k \geq 0$, let $R_k=T_y^k$ be the time of the $k$ th return to $y$, and for $k \geq 1$ let $r_k$ $=R_k-R_{k-1}$ be the $k$ th interarrival time. Use the strong Markov property to conclude that under $P_y$, the vectors $v_k=\left(r_k, X_{R_{k-1}}, \ldots, X_{R_k-1}\right), k \geq 1$ are i.i.d.
What confuses me is that theorem 5.2.5 as below requires that the function should be (consistently) bounded but this can not be verified when it comes to $v_k$.
Theorem 5.2.5. Strong Markov property. Suppose that for each $n, Y_n$ : $\Omega_0 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is measurable and $\left|Y_n\right| \leq M$ for all $n$. Then
$$
E_\mu\left(Y_N \circ \theta_N \mid \mathcal{F}_N\right)=E_{X_N} Y_N \text { on }\{N<\infty\}
$$
where the right-hand side is $\varphi(x, n)=E_x Y_n$ evaluated at $x=X_N, n=N$.
